# Transformation of sentence into negative

Tags: syntactic-analysis, negation

I have this sentence:

> This is all I can say.

I have to turn it into a negative statement.

I have tried a few things and ended up with:

> I can't say more than this.

Am I right in rewording it like this? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Do you mean 'negative' in a grammatical sense?  I'm asking because the answer you give is correct grammatically, but means the same.

Comment: Transformation means that having same meaning but grammatically negative

Comment: Ok, then your answer is right.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want. Do you need to have 'can' in your answer?

Comment: I can say no more than this. I cannot say any more than this.

Comment: If you want to be "whimsical" you can try this (which is also correct): I cannot not say no more than this. (if you want to play with someone's brains a bit).

Comment: What's with all this "$[]$" nonsense? Is your keyboard broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is all I can say

"I cannot tell you more either because I do not know or I do not wish to (do so)."

> I can't say more than this

*Supra.*

The meaning is the same, and it is now a "negative" [grammar] statement. So, yes, you are correct.

Other ways to do so? While maintaining a "negative" structure:

> I can say no more than/of this.
>
> I cannot elaborate any further.
>
> There are no other things to say (on the matter).

Comment: Surely "I can say no more" and "There are no other things to say" both have a positive structure (although the meaning is negative) since the verbs are positive. "I cannot elaborate further" is negative because the auxilliary verb _can_ is negated.

Comment: You, sir, appear to be correct :)